# Azure App Service to App Service communication on TLS1.2 failing

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

I have an Azure App Service with Stack General setting ASP.NET v4.7. However, in the web.config target runtime version is 4.5.1.

I have another Azure App Service which hosts a Linux container.

The first one is set to use TLS 1.2.
I am initiating requests from .NET App(first) to Linux container(second).
When the Second one, Linux container is set to use TLS 1.2 requests fail, but when set to TLS 1.0 requests process successfully.

Has anyone experienced this issue?

Comment: Would be great if you can post the exception as well so that we can get deep into what 'failing' here is.

Comment: `the underlying connection was closed: an unexpected error occurred on a send` getting this exception.

Answer (score 2):

From the post it is tricky to narrow down on your issue but a couple of things you can try.

- Ensure no hard coding of TLS version. On the contrary, you can try hardcoding the TLS version with `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`. Try to run. If it works, you'll have the clarity that there is not other issue and you need to switch to right .NET version.
- Target your .NET Framework version 4.7 and above. You say your target runtime version is 4.5.1 which won't help sending requests with latest TLS version by default.
- `<system.web><httpRuntime targetFramework>` in web.config should show the intended version of the .NET.
- Last but not least it is always good to patiently read the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls) and you might figure out the issue yourself.